# Problem when trying to play mp3 file with QMediaPlayer PyQt5

Tags: python, web-scraping, pyqt5, mp3, qmediaplayer

Mp3 file downloaded from SoundCloud with SoundScrape cannot be played by QMediaPlayer in PyQT5. There is no error but cannot play the file (QMediaPlayer::play).

```
# Here I'm loading the media, there's some comments because I was trying some stuff

import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.uic.properties import QtCore

class Player(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Player, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setFixedSize(1920, 1080)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.currentPlaylist = QMediaPlaylist()

        self.player = QMediaPlayer(self)
        self.player.mediaStatusChanged.connect(self.mediaStatusChange)
        self.player.positionChanged.connect(self.positionChanged)
        self.player.durationChanged.connect(self.durationChanged)

        self.player.setPlaylist(self.currentPlaylist)
        self.load_playlist()

    def on_item_clicked(self, item):

        if self.musicListWidget.currentItem().isSelected() == False:
            self.musicListWidget.currentItem().setSelected(True)

        data = self.musicListWidget.selectedIndexes()[0]
        index = data.row()
        self.playMusic(index=index)


    def playMusic(self, index=0):
        self.player.setPlaylist(self.currentPlaylist)
        self.player.playlist().setCurrentIndex(index)

        self.player.play()
        self.player.setVolume(self.musicVolumeSlider.value())

    def load_playlist(self):
        self.musicListWidget.addItem(
            os.path.basename('C:\MyStuff\Programming_Stuff\License\Eargasm\songs\Mihai Pol - Goneta.mp3'))
        self.currentPlaylist.addMedia(QMediaContent(

### here will be the full path where the file was downloaded
           QUrl.fromLocalFile('C:\MyStuff\Programming_Stuff\License\Eargasm\songs\Mihai Pol - Goneta.mp3')))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Player()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

#### Here I'm downloading the file ( download_via_soundcloud )

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
import subprocess
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

class SoundcloudScrapper:

    DOWNLOAD_PATH = 'C:/MyStuff/Programming_Stuff/License/Eargasm/songs'
    FILE_URL = "C:\MyStuff\Programming_Stuff\License\Eargasm\songs"
    SOUNDCLOUD_URL = 'https://www.soundcloud.com'
    SEARCH_QUERY = '/search?q='

    def get_search_input_by_title(self, title):
        """
        :param title: The title of the track
        :return: Search query of the track by SoundCloud rules
        """
        search_query = ""

        for char in title:
            if char == ' ':
                search_query += '%20'
            elif char == '[':
                search_query += '%5B'
            elif char == ']':
                search_query += '%5D'
            else:
                search_query += char

        return search_query

    def download_via_soundcloud(self,artist: str, title: str):
        """
        :param artist: The artist of the track
        :param title: The title of the track
        :return: True if the track has been downloaded successfully, False otherwise
        """
        track_title = artist + ' - ' + title
        search_query_value = self.get_search_input_by_title(track_title)
        soundcloud_url = self.SOUNDCLOUD_URL + self.SEARCH_QUERY + search_query_value

        url = requests.get(soundcloud_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'lxml')
        songs = soup.select("li h2 a")

        ### if there is nothing on soundcloud
        if not songs:
            return False
### checking top 2 songs from search result
        for index in range(0,1):
            song = songs[index]

            href_track_found = song.get('href')
            title_track_found = self.clean_soundcloud_title_found(song.text)
            ratio = SequenceMatcher(None, track_title, title_track_found).ratio()

            if ratio > 0.5:
                output = subprocess.check_output("soundscrape " + self.SOUNDCLOUD_URL + href_track_found + " -p " + self.DOWNLOAD_PATH, shell=True)  ## .decode("utf-8")

                return True

        return False

    def clean_soundcloud_title_found(self, track_title):

        track_title = re.sub("([\[]).*?([\]])", "", track_title)
        ### parts that can mislead us to a small ratio
        possible_blockers = ["A1.", "A2.", "B1.", "B2.", "C1.", "C2.", "D1.", "D2.", "E1.", "E2.", "F1.", "F2.",
                             "A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2", "D1", "D2", "E1", "E2", "F1", "F2", "preview", "Preview" ]

        for blocker in possible_blockers:
            if blocker in track_title:
                track_title = track_title.replace(blocker, "")

        return track_title

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
    scrapper = SoundcloudScrapper()
    scrapper.download_via_soundcloud("Mihai Pol", "Science Friction")
```

SoundScrape : https://github.com/Miserlou/SoundScrape/blob/master/soundscrape/soundscrape.py

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: basically an mp3 is not recognized by the QMediaPlayer in PyQT5 and I don't see why ..

Comment: I want to know how you get that mp3 to analyze if there is a problem in the download, or a problem in the reading or another type of problem, for this reason I have required an MRE, without that information it is impossible to help you and consequently I will vote to close your question.

Comment: Edit your question and clearly describe the procedure you use in addition to the code necessary to execute it, you already have more than a year in the community and you should know how to implement a good question, if you don't know how to do it then check [ask] and pass the [tour]. Code and relevant information should not be in the comments but in your question

Comment: what are `SOUNDCLOUD_URL` and `href_track_found`?

Comment: I've added in the code,  SOUNDCLOUD_URL it's the base URL for the soundcloud, and href_track_found it's the href link for the specific track I've found scraping

Comment: with `print(output)` I get `b'Problem downloading [404]: Item Not Found\n'`. Are you sure that these data are correct?

Comment: It seems that the track has been remove, I will replace href_track_found with '/rickygrig/mihai-pol-science-friction'

Comment: str(output) should look like   b'Active code page: 65001\r\nTrack already downloaded: Mihai Pol - Science Friction\r\n'

Comment: It throws me an exception : mmm, `requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 429 Client Error: Unknown for url: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/272627909/stream?limit=200&client_id=175c043157ffae2c6d5fed16c3d95a4c` going to the url  `https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/272627909/stream?limit=200&client_id=175c043157ffae2c6d5fed16c3d95a4`  I get `{"errors":[{"meta":{"rate_limit":{"bucket":"by-client","max_nr_of_requests":15000,"time_window":"PT24H","name":"plays"},"remaining_requests":0,"reset_time":"2020/03/27 18:46:22 +0000"}}]}`

Comment: The idea is that SoundCloud allow per ClientID 15000 requests, and they re gone very fast because this SoundScraper API is being used by a lot of people, please go to scrapper.py file and replace CLIENT_ID with '454aeaee30d3533d6d8f448556b50f23'

Comment: It works for me, I think that another part of your code that you do not show is generating this problem, so now if it is necessary for a real MRE, read the link if you do not know.

Comment: I've added both classes, but It's really weird because I used to command from terminal  ' soundcrape URL'   and then just a simply load into my QMediaPlayer and didn't work ... whereas another mp3 file from the same folder worked

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding, check now please

Comment: I suspect that the problem may be the PATH (spaces, backslash, etc), I am going to join both parts so you can see how I would do it and how I would get a proper path without using hardcode. For your part you could try changing the name of the downloaded .mp3 to something like foo.mp3 and try paths that do not contain spaces to verify if that is the cause of the problem.

Comment: I've tried that, and don't work neither .. firstly this i was suspecting too. The file is found by QMediaPlayer because if it doesn't it will be an infinite loop, but is not playable .. :(

Comment: I've tried in a folder where i have many mp3 and one downloaded via SoundScrape, all sharing same path, the SoundScrape downloaded file is the single one not playable

Comment: if you can join both parts and make it work, would be perfect ^ ^